# Grab HTML tag value and assign to PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have JavaScript to change the value of an input tag whenever I open my popup in which it all executes successfully. When I inspect the tag, the value is exactly what it should be every time. Now within that popup I have, I just want to echo out the value using my PHP variable but this doesn't seem to work. I understand the whole concept of PHP is server side and JavaScript it client side but because the value is changed it should not matter as the value is there and PHP should be able to pick it up even when I reopen the popup.

Any idea how to achieve this?

My code is below. I can't have the page reload (e.g., use post methods and such).

HTML input tag:

```
<td class="alarmvalue" style="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="tracknameneeds" id="tracknameneeds" style="text-align:center;" class="form-control" value="">
</td>
```

Code trying to echo input tags value:

```
<?php 
$trackname = "<script>document.getElementByID('tracknameneeds').value;</script>";
?>   


<!-- Play Options localstorage etc -->
<div class="context-menu">
    <div id="modal-pl-playpopup" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-pl-playpopup-label" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-pl-clear-label">Play Options</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Choose from the following...<br>
                    <p>You Chose: <?php echo $trackname;?></p>
                    <br> 
                    <br>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" style="width:100%" data-cmd="add" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle sx"></i> Add To Queue</a><br> <div style="padding-top:5px"></div>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" style="width:100%" data-cmd="addplay" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-play sx"></i> Add And Play</a><br><div style="padding-top:5px"></div>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" style="width:100%" data-cmd="addreplaceplay" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-share-square-o sx"></i> Add, Replace And Play</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
var tracknamepopup;
tracknamepopup = o.data("path"); //assign song name to variable
document.getElementById('tracknameneeds').value = tracknamepopup; //assign the grabbed song name to inputs value to try grab that in php
```

Comment: Bear in mind: PHP runs on the *server* side. JS runs *in the browser*. By the time JS **starts** to run - PHP has already **completed** execution. It is the *browser* where that context is, the "PHP variable" is long gone.

Comment: We cant assign a js variable to php variable but the vice versa is possible.

Comment: Thats still the case? Damn.. I thought by assigning a value which changes it should still work? As the value is there..

Comment: use ajax for this

Comment: The JS is at the bottom @MartavisGriffin. Thanks though.

Comment: Ajax? I know of it and all but honestly.. I would not know where to begin to make a workable workaround. @Ish

Comment: @Ish I don't think OP needs to be confused any more with buzzwords

Comment: Read what I wrote: the PHP variable already **died**, `expired`, *became extinct* when the JS code runs. No way to change it. You have to restructure your thinking to separate the concerns of being on the server side, and the browser side. Believe me, it will be a great revelation. (Once that is done, there is room for proceeding with concepts like Ajax)

Comment: Would anyone know a workaround then? Give me any idea how i can echo the js? The purpose is to echo out the song name when you open the popup and it should echo out the song name for each popup if you get me. When i open the popup, i save the song title to the inputs value hoping to echo out that but guess there is no way for that..

Comment: I updated with my js code. Thats what im using to assign to input value.

Comment: Not the way you expect: you need to use the [request parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) to pass values from the browser to the server for this, by issuing a new request to  the server (aka, load the page with the parameters attached). **But first please promise to use proper [input sanitization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_input_and_output_handling)!**

Comment: you could open the popup in an Ajax call and send the post data:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041220/how-to-generate-popup-after-ajax-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did might not be the best solution but worked perfectly.

Have a blank tag (In my case i used a header (h1,h2 etc tag)) and give it an id. Use js to manipulate the Inner-HTML to display the current track.

HTML:

```
<h2 id="songbacktag"></h2>
```

JS:

```
var tracknamepopup;
tracknamepopup = o.data("path");
document.getElementById("songbacktag").innerHTML = tracknamepopup;
```

Answer (score 3):

All HTML code and Javscript execution is done (on client side) after PHP execution is complete on Server Side and response is sent to the client.

So you can not bind or assign HTML tag value to PHP directly.

But you can set it by AJAX and store it in session for next script execution on PHP.

Code in JS should be :

```
var tracknamepopup;
tracknamepopup = o.data("path"); //assign song name to variable
document.getElementById('tracknameneeds').value = tracknamepopup; //assign the grabbed song name to inputs value to try grab that in php
// you can write code for call update session varible using ajax
updateServerSession('tracknameneeds',tracknamepopup);
function updateServerSession(session_index,value) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "update_ajax?index"+session_index+"&value="+value, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Code in **update_ajax.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION[$_GET['index']]=$_GET['value'];
```

Comment: And with this i can still echo out $trackname and use the following code in trackname?: `<?php 
$trackname = "<script>document.getElementByID('tracknameneeds').value;</script>";
?> ` or how would i do it? Thanks by the way! appreciate it.

Comment: Unfortunately its not possible... because scope of PHP variable & execution is completed after responding (send output) to client..

Comment: So how would i be able to echo out the new variable? Is the code above not making this possible or?

Comment: With the above,  how do i retrieve the value of "tracknameneeds"?

Comment: In your next script execution you will get value of tracknameneedsfrom session variable by using `$_SESSION['tracknameneeds']`

Comment: So my page would need to reload in order to grab the information? I used: `$trackname = $_SESSION['tracknameneeds'];` but doesnt work.

Comment: have you started session in your top of code in first line?

Comment: I did indeed, the first line has: `<?PHP 
session_start();
?>`

Comment: I made a new page called: "update_ajax.php" with the code: `<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION[$_GET['index']]=$_GET['value'];
?>`

That correct?

Answer (score 3):

I think easiest way is to just use a get variable:

```
window.open("http://www.yoursite.com/popup.php?trackname=".concat(document.getElementByID('tracknameneeds').value));
```

and then use

```
$_GET['trackname']
```

But you should escape all get variables before posting!